# Drupal 8 - Allow Insert Media icon to select existing images using CCK Editor

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, cck

I’m pretty good when it comes to using php to program something into Drupal 8.

But configuring Drupal 8 to do something is a bit more difficult for me.

I have two different buttons in CCK editor for adding images.

The first one with the dialogue that says "Insert Image" only allows file uploads.

[image: Insert Image Dialouge]

The second Icon allows me to choose files already in the system, but only inserts a link to the image.  I would like to add this image inline.

[image: Select media to embed]

I have been to the entity browser config screen and added several widgets, but none of the "widgets" allow me to insert an image inline.  Every widget wants to insert a link to the image
/admin/config/content/entity_browser/

How can I add a widget that allows me to choose an existing image, and inserts that image inline instead of inserting a link to the image?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with [File Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_browser) module.

It's description: This module provides a default Entity Browser that lets you browse and select your files in a nice-looking, mobile-ready Masonry based interface, and upload files using the Dropzonejs module.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the core image upload.  The problem was images were being uploaded as "files" so you couldn't insert them using the entity browser.

[image: New Image Upload]

I added a new widget here:
/admin/config/content/entity_browser/media_entity_browser/widgets

This is what the new widget settings are.  I hope this helps someone else who's having issues configuring drupal 8.

[image]